# Use LoadStateEventArgs e in whole the whole class

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I am an beginner in making a Windows store app. this app is based on C# and XAML. On the first page the data is send to the second page on the press off a tile. It will give a parameter to the second page like this:

```
void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var groupId = ((ProductGroup)e.ClickedItem).UniqueId;
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(GroupView), groupId);
}
```

on the second page i retreive the UniqueId given in the groupId like this:

```
private async void navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
{      
    string uniqueId = ((string)e.NavigationParameter);
    var result = await backEnd.getJsonData(uniqueId);
    this.DefaultViewModel["Groups"] = result;
}
```

Now i want to use the uniqueId in this whole page. Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do this: Create a class variable just for the UniqueId in your Page, or store the value somewhere, such as your ViewModel.

Try this:

```
private async void navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
{      
    string uniqueId = ((string)e.NavigationParameter);
    var result = await backEnd.getJsonData(uniqueId);
    this.DefaultViewModel["Groups"] = result;
    this.DefaultViewModel["UniqueId"] = uniqueId;
}
```

Then, whenever you need to go back and get it, just use:

```
this.DefaultViewModel["UniqueId"];
```

Hope this helps and happy coding!